# I receive the error invalid operands to binary + (have ‘float’ and ‘float *’) sum+=number; ,in my program to calculate an average of numbers?

Tags: c, average

I am new to c.
I get this error code :14:8: error: invalid operands to binary + (have ‘float’ and ‘float *’)
     sum+=number;invalid operands to binary + (have ‘float’ and ‘float *’)
     sum+=number;
This is my code

```
/*Program to calculate the average of numbers*/
#include<stdio.h>

int main()  {
    int n;
    float number[50],average,sum;
    printf("Enter the amount of numbers you want to average:/s");
    scanf("%d",n);

    while ((n>0 || n<=50))
    {
        printf("Enter the numbers you want to average:/s");
        scanf("%f\n",number[n] );
        sum+=number;
        average=sum/n;
    }
    printf("average=/s",average );
    return 0;
}
```

Any advice on how to fix this error and how my program could be improved?

Comment: What is the value of sum, before this line: `sum+=number;` is reached for the first time ?

Comment: On the line above you read to `number[n]`. Is that not the one you want to add to the sum? Also, `n` is not changing inside the loop, so how is it going to terminate?

Comment: number is an array, you cant add a float to an array. Also lots more wrong here

Comment: Note: `while ((n>0 || n<=50))` is always true. Prbbly you want: `while ( n> 0 && n <= 50)` And you'll need some ampersands: `scanf("%d", &n);`

Comment: sum += number; You are trying to add an array to a float. That doesn't make sense. Also, use double, not float, unless you have a good reason to do otherwise. If you don't know which one to choose, use double.

Answer (score 0):

here number is an array of float and sum is a float type variable. you cant add an array and a variable. another problem here is, your while loop will generate an infinite loop. please checkout the conditions and their relation. also you need to put ampersand (&) before variable name in scanf.